# Combine multiple Google sheet scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying for weeks now to solve this issue but did not have any luck (I am pretty new to Google Scripting). So I am posting here hoping some of you managed to solve this before me !

I have multiple scripts in Google sheets and I would like to put them all together to run everything on a schedule.
The scripts are running well separately but not together. I see mostly conflict between script 2 and 3
Basically this is to get datas from an URL, and clean them. Here is a description of the script :

1 - Get the data from an URL

2 - Clean column 6

3 - Clean column 3

4 - Change number format

Here is the script :

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {

  // Provide the full URL of the CSV file.
  var csvUrl = "https://mycsvdata.testsite";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}


// 2 - CLEAN CATEGORIES
function clean() {

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var deleteSelectedRows = removeThenSetNewVals();
  var runTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000;
  Logger.log("Runtime is: " + runTime + " seconds");
};

function removeThenSetNewVals(){
  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var pattern = new RegExp("Accessories|case|pouch...");
var columnToSearch = 5;
var newRangeVals = range.getValues().filter(r => r[0] && !pattern.exec(r[columnToSearch]))  
range.clearContent();
var numRows = newRangeVals.length;
var newRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, numRows, newRangeVals[0].length).setValues(newRangeVals);
var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
sheet.deleteRows(numRows + 1, maxRows - numRows);
};

// 3 - CLEAN NAME

function clean2() {

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var deleteSelectedRows = removeThenSetNewVals2();
  var runTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000;
  Logger.log("Runtime is: " + runTime + " seconds");
};

function removeThenSetNewVals2(){
  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var pattern = new var pattern = new RegExp("Accessories|case|pouch...");
var columnToSearch = 2;
var newRangeVals = range.getValues().filter(r => r[0] && !pattern.exec(r[columnToSearch]))  
range.clearContent();
var numRows = newRangeVals.length;
var newRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, numRows, newRangeVals[0].length).setValues(newRangeVals);
var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
sheet.deleteRows(numRows + 1, maxRows - numRows);
};


// 4 - CLEAN PRICE

function decimal(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("D1:D");
// Always show 3 decimal points
cell.setNumberFormat("00");
}
```

Thank you very much for any help !

Comment: How do you start these scripts, what is the exact issue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I run the scripts individually I get a clean result but if I run them together the columns are not clean properly, some content that should have been deleted is still there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CopyTo in Sheets Stops Working without Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675162/copyto-in-sheets-stops-working-without-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am curious what you mean by run them together. But it is easy enough to have one function call the other functions and then using a trigger, set sheets to run the main function on the schedule you want

```
function daily() {
importCSVFromWeb();
clean();
removeThenSetNewVals();
clean2();
removeThenSetNewVals2();
decimal();

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is simple and could solve my problem (I am pretty new to this), but when I do that I get the following error : 
Exception: Those rows are out of bounds.

Comment: Antoine, you are welcome. Please mark the answer as helpful. Regarding those errors, my suggestion is to step thru the code using the debugger and examine your variables as you step through the script. This typically helps me find where something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods that might help you - Spreadsheet.flush() and Lockservice. I cannot tell for sure if it will work without having the insight into your code, but you can try. Wrap each of your method calls into:

```
const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
try{
    lock.waitLock(30000)
    method() // run your method here
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
} finally{
    lock.releaseLock()
}
```